# Setting HBase Column Family history to infinity

Tags: java, hive, hbase

I have created a HBase table with version = 3 and now want to alter it so that it can store infinite number of updates.

```
ALTER 'table_name',NAME=>'cf',VERSION=>3
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set the number of max versions to infinite. You have to set a number as a max.

However, according to HBase :

> It is not recommended setting the number of max versions to an
>   exceedingly high level (e.g., hundreds or more) unless those old
>   values are very dear to you because this will greatly increase
>   StoreFile size.

http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#schema.versions